# How to implement @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) into canDeactivate guard directives?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my app, we have lots of components with lots of form fields. So whenever the user changes something in the form and without saving the changes if the user wants to navigate to another component he is getting a warning message using canDeactivate. However, instead of navigating to the app, if the user closes the tab then he is not getting the warning message anymore. I have resolved this issue using `window:beforeunload` inside the component like this:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  public oncloseTab( event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.shouldWarnForUnsaved()) {  // shouldWarnForUnsaved tells if anything changes in the form 
      return window.confirm('There is the unsaved message. Are you sure you want to close the tab?');
    }
  }
```

However as I said I have lots of components, so I have to do the copy-paste this above code several times in several components. I am just curious, is there any way I could achieve using `candeactivate` guard directive?  My goal is, I will implement the `beforeunload` once in the `candeactivate` guard directives so that I do not have to repeat the same code in several times.

Can anybody have any clue how to do this?

Comment: are you using reactive forms?

Comment: I am using template-driven form actually. @PoulKruijt

Comment: is there a way to detect what is the event occurring inside the component in canDeactivate guard? @PoulKruijt

Comment: Closing of the tab won't trigger a `canDeactivate` call, so that won't work

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you implement your template-driven form?

Comment: here is an example 
<form #reqForm="ngForm" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" ">
          </form>
@PoulKruijt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232536/discussion-between-kazi-and-poul-kruijt).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a template driven example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a custom directive and add this to every form which has a `formGroup` directive attached to it if you use reactive forms, or `ngForm` when you use template driven:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[formUnloadWarning]'
})
export class FormUnloadWarningDirective {
  private form = this.reactiveForm || this.templateForm;

  constructor(
    @Self() @Optional() private reactiveForm: FormGroup,
    @Self() @Optional() private templateForm: NgForm
  ) {}

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload() {
    if (this.form.dirty) {
      return window.confirm('There is the unsaved message....');
    }
  }
}
```

Which you can then use on your forms like this:

Reactive forms:

```
<form formUnloadWarning [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <!-- your controls -->
</form>
```

Template driven:

```
<form formUnloadWarning #reqForm="ngForm">
  <!-- your form -->
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a nice solution. I am utterly grateful to you.  However, ts shows an error while using AbstractControlDirective . So after removing the AbstractControlDirective, ts was not complaining at all. @PoulKruijt

Comment: @Kazi you are right :) I didn't test the code, so that's what happens. Apparently `NgForm` extends `AbstractControlDirective`, but `FormGroup` just extends `AbstractControl`. So removing the type declaration is okay. TypeScript can figure it out. If you are never going to use reactive forms (even though it works very nice), you can remove all that logic and just keep the `templateForm`

Comment: Unfortunately, the custom text also not working as a warning. is it the browser issue? @PoulKruijt

Comment: @Kazi custom text is not supported anymore in browsers. Has been like that for a while now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you run your @HostListener method in `app.component.ts`, you can get a global event listener. However, you will need to write a global service for `this.shouldWarnForUnsaved ()` method. The shortest way is to turn each of your forms into a directive and define these operations in the directive you created.